# How do you make a Kalanchoe blossfeldiana bloom?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, flowering

This plant was beautiful and full of flowers. They all withered away. Now the buds just don't want to open. I read somewhere that Kalanchoe at home needs to be bloomed by doing some tricks like putting in shade for some time and then in sun etc. Not sure, as I had placed it in very bright indirect light and it was still not blooming.

Should I just place this in indirect bright light and wait? Or there is really a way to make them bloom?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique to make this bloom is similar to a seasonal cactus,

1. Periods of light and dark - 14 hours of darkness & 10 hours of light.  You can use a black double over shade cloth or landscape fabric during the 14 hours.  You may need a grow light to get 10 hours of bright sun in winter, depending on how far north you live.
2. Cooler Temperatures - Give it temperatures of 50-60F(10-15C)
3. Withhold water - Give it a soak and then do not water it again until you start to see flower buds, this maybe up to 2 months.  This is why it is important to have cooler temperatures.
4. Time - 6-8 weeks

Comment: This looks kinda hard, but will give it a try. Thank you, Aloe Vera.